# How to upload file to the page path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, jquery-plugins

I search it every where but not found right answer, I'm trying to upload file using jQuery plugin, But I don't know to where file save when I upload file using this plugin.
My need is when file upload it save automatically to the page path.

Plugin Url:

```
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php
```

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/T9g5M/)

Comment: Try this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file to a website you need a server listening to request on the end. Jquery can be used to simplify getting the file to the server but once there the server has to accept it and copy it to the hard drive. Think about it like this, it would be a real problem if anyone could post anything to your server and have it be copied to your server. Hope this helps, or at least points you in the right direction.